# Create a simple Natural Earth topographic map with Mapbox

Tags: style, mapbox, basemap, natural-earth

I want embed a Mapbox map on a website and put some placemarks on it (I already did so, but that was a year ago and everything was easier back then ;)). I am a bit confused with the new Mapbox Studio software, one has to use to create custom styled maps with Mapbox now.

What I want is actually quite simple: a map that looks more or less exactly like the first one in this blog post:

https://www.mapbox.com/blog/eight-new-terrain-baselayer-maps-available-mapbox/

So just the Natural Earth terrain baselayer and nothing else. I probably would change the water colour, but that's it.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two quick options:

- download the NE topography .tif and create a MapBox Studio source from it (see the [guide on source projects](https://www.mapbox.com/guides/getting-started-studio/#source)).  Upload it to MapBox and create a simple style project to render it.  Since the raster is already styled, the CartoCSS would be pretty minimal: just apply the `raster-opacity: 1;` property.
- try to recreate the NE topography style using MapBox's terrain sources.  A little more work behind this, but you get total control over the terrain styling and don't have to worry about hosting your own source projects.  The *MapBox Outdoors* style project that ships with MapBox Studio (and references MapBox's own terrain layers) would probably be a great place to start.  For reference, see these [first three design guides](https://www.mapbox.com/guides/map-design/).

And a third option, just use TileMill to generate the tileset from NE layers.